# Integrating elastic search with rails 4 on linux mint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, elasticsearch

Since I integrated elasticsearch I get this error when I try to navigate to users_sign_in_path

I read that I have to edit the file elasticsearch.rake but I don't know where that file would be on linux mint there's no /lib/tasks directory for me to create the file in

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound in Devise::SessionsController#create
[404] {"error":"DocumentMissingException[[users][4] [user][3]: document missing]","status":404}
```